# General network error on adodb with mobile broadband

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, mobile, adoconnection, broadband

We have applications that synchronize some database (sqlserver).
Technician Database (SQLExpress 2008 32bit) and on the server side SqlServer 2008 R2 64 bit.

In the synchronize application I to some scripts to sync. the database from the techician to the server.
Now I get an errors like [DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]

I've made some log about the error

```
--21/10/2013 11:05:12------------Update on t_intervention_mission--------------------------------
 Old Values:
   ID=0,RowID={06938E13-F068-437D-A454-3E17B4C7CCC6},IntCardID= NULL,IntCardRowID={69D86DD9-55E5-450F-BC72-93FE2DB5BA1E},MissionID= NULL,MissionRowID={7D1F046F-C82A-42AA-9712-00D4F7FEC5BF},Duration=CONVERT(DATETIME,'1899-12-30 00:00:00.000', 102),Number=1,InCalculation=0,KindID= NULL,KindRowID={D2BD32AD-5926-4AF6-9258-F52F453800A8},WorkTime=0,PayerReference='r',WorkOut=0,ImmovableProperty=1,VatPercent=21,DurationChange=0,DefaultMissionPrice=0,ProductCount=0,DeliverProductPrice=0,DeliverWorkPrice=0,DeliverTransportPrice=0,DeliverMissionPrice=0,DeliverTotalPrice=0,ActiveProductPrice=0,ActiveWorkPrice=0,ActiveTransportPrice=0,ActiveMissionPrice=0,ActiveTotalPrice=0,TariffID= NULL,TariffRowID= NULL,WorkCostPercent=0,WorkCostPlus=0,WorkAmountPercent=0,WorkAmountPlus=0,ProductAmountPercent=0,ProductAmountPlus=0,TransportCostPercent=0,TransportCostPlus=0,TransportAmountPercent=0,TransportAmountPlus=0,MissionAmountPercent=0,MissionAmountPlus=0,DateCreate=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-10-21 11:02:36.083', 102),DateChange=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-10-21 11:05:00.620', 102),WorkStationCreate='SIX001',WorkStationChange='SIX001',ContractPrice=0,IsSafeCondition= NULL
Script:
   update t_intervention_mission set PayerReference='r',DateChange=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-10-21 11:05:00.620', 102) where RowID = '{06938E13-F068-437D-A454-3E17B4C7CCC6}'
--ERROR--EOleException--------------------------------------------------------------------
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]Algemene netwerkfout. Raadpleeg de netwerkdocumentatie
 On script:  update t_intervention_mission set PayerReference='r',DateChange=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-10-21 11:05:00.620', 102) where RowID = '{06938E13-F068-437D-A454-3E17B4C7CCC6}'

 Connection:AdoConnectionServer
 Number = -2147467259
 NativeError = 11
 Source = Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
 Description = [DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]Algemene netwerkfout. Raadpleeg de netwerkdocumentatie.
 Helpfile = 
 SQLState = HY018
 ConnectionTimeOut = 60
 CommandTimeout = 120
--21/10/2013 11:05:41----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the log the script want to make an update.
I also set  a timeless ping in command promp to the sqlserver.
When the script execute the update then the ping goes to time out.

this error is only when I have a mobile broadband connection.
When the technician arrive to the firm then the laptop find the wifi of the firm and the scripts can be done.
The error occure only in a mobile broadband connection.

```
function TLogFile.SqlExec (StrSql : String; AdoConnection : TADOConnection; ARec: _RecordSet): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  try
    ARec := AdoConnection.Execute(StrSql, cmdText);
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      E.Message:= E.Message+ craConstant.CRLF+
                  'On script: '+StrSql+ craConstant.CRLF+
                  'Connection:'+ AdoConnection.Name;
      if (E.ClassType = EOleException) and (AdoConnection.Errors.Count > 0) then
      begin
        E.Message:= E.Message+ craConstant.CRLF+
                    'Number ='+IntToStr(AdoConnection.Errors[0].Number)+CRLF+
                    'NativeError ='+IntToStr(AdoConnection.Errors[0].NativeError)+CRLF+
                    'Source ='+AdoConnection.Errors[0].Source+CRLF+
                    'Description ='+AdoConnection.Errors[0].Description+CRLF+
                    'Helpfile ='+AdoConnection.Errors[0].HelpFile+CRLF+
                    'SQLState ='+AdoConnection.Errors[0].SQLState;
      end;
      self.HndException:= E;
      Result := -1;

      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I did some change in the function sqlexec:

```
function TLogFile.SqlExec (StrSql : String; AdoConnection : TADOConnection): Integer;
var
  oQuerySql: TADOQuery;
begin
  Result := 0;

  oQuerySql:= TADOQuery.Create(Nil);
  try
    oQuerySql.Connection:= AdoConnection;
    oQuerySql.CommandTimeout:= AdoConnection.CommandTimeout;
    oQuerySql.SQL.Add(StrSql);

    try
      oQuerySql.ExecSQL;
    except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
        E.Message:= E.Message+ craConstant.CRLF+
                    'On script: '+StrSql+ craConstant.CRLF+
                    'Connection:'+ AdoConnection.Name;
        if (E.ClassType = EOleException) and (AdoConnection.Errors.Count > 0) then
        begin
          E.Message:= E.Message+ craConstant.CRLF+
                      'Number = '+IntToStr(AdoConnection.Errors[0].Number)+CRLF+
                      'NativeError = '+IntToStr(AdoConnection.Errors[0].NativeError)+CRLF+
                      'Source = '+AdoConnection.Errors[0].Source+CRLF+
                      'Description = '+AdoConnection.Errors[0].Description+CRLF+
                      'Helpfile = '+AdoConnection.Errors[0].HelpFile+CRLF+
                      'SQLState = '+AdoConnection.Errors[0].SQLState+CRLF+
                      'ConnectionTimeOut = '+IntToStr(AdoConnection.ConnectionTimeout) +CRLF+
                      'CommandTimeout = '+IntToStr(AdoConnection.CommandTimeout);
        end;
        self.HndException:= E;
        Result := -1;

        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(oQuerySql);
  end;
end;
```

This change was OK for 3 days , Now I get back the error on an insert script like

```
--21/10/2013 14:11:05------------Insert on t_intervention_mission----------------------------------------------------
  Old Values:
  ID=0,RowID={53C5780D-B683-45C9-B942-018091DD0435},IntCardID= NULL,IntCardRowID={0709FB3B-1CDD-4E2B-BAC6-4FB6A952F788},MissionID= NULL,MissionRowID={C24234F2-DD1F-4B3B-B81D-3D13384CC573},Duration=CONVERT(DATETIME,'1899-12-30 00:20:00.000', 102),Number=1,InCalculation=0,KindID= NULL,KindRowID={77387E4C-604A-4653-B490-38A6B9C5A8E5},WorkTime=0,PayerReference= NULL,WorkOut=1,ImmovableProperty=1,VatPercent=0,DurationChange=0,DefaultMissionPrice=0,ProductCount=0,DeliverProductPrice=0,DeliverWorkPrice=0,DeliverTransportPrice=0,DeliverMissionPrice=0,DeliverTotalPrice=0,ActiveProductPrice=0,ActiveWorkPrice=13.54,ActiveTransportPrice=11.01,ActiveMissionPrice=0,ActiveTotalPrice=24.55,TariffID= NULL,TariffRowID={DADB09D9-A760-4213-98AA-47E090EAB1FD},WorkCostPercent=0,WorkCostPlus=0,WorkAmountPercent=30,WorkAmountPlus=0,ProductAmountPercent=0,ProductAmountPlus=0,TransportCostPercent=0,TransportCostPlus=0,TransportAmountPercent=0,TransportAmountPlus=0,MissionAmountPercent=0,MissionAmountPlus=0,DateCreate=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-02 08:37:54.530', 102),DateChange=CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-02 08:38:06.460', 102),WorkStationCreate='SIX001',WorkStationChange='SIX001',ContractPrice=0,IsSafeCondition= NULL
 Script:
   insert into t_intervention_mission     (RowID,IntCardRowID,MissionRowID,Duration,Number,InCalculation,KindRowID,WorkTime,WorkOut,ImmovableProperty,VatPercent,DurationChange,DefaultMissionPrice,ProductCount,DeliverProductPrice,DeliverWorkPrice,DeliverTransportPrice,DeliverMissionPrice,DeliverTotalPrice,ActiveProductPrice,ActiveWorkPrice,ActiveTransportPrice,ActiveMissionPrice,ActiveTotalPrice,TariffRowID,WorkCostPercent,WorkCostPlus,WorkAmountPercent,WorkAmountPlus,ProductAmountPercent,ProductAmountPlus,TransportCostPercent,TransportCostPlus,TransportAmountPercent,TransportAmountPlus,MissionAmountPercent,MissionAmountPlus,DateCreate,DateChange,WorkStationCreate,WorkStationChange,ContractPrice) values ('{53C5780D-B683-45C9-B942-018091DD0435}','{0709FB3B-1CDD-4E2B-BAC6-4FB6A952F788}','{C24234F2-DD1F-4B3B-B81D-3D13384CC573}',CONVERT(DATETIME,'1899-12-30 00:20:00.000', 102),1,0,'{77387E4C-604A-4653-B490-38A6B9C5A8E5}',0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13.54,11.01,0,24.55,'{DADB09D9-A760-4213-98AA-47E090EAB1FD}',0,0,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-02 08:37:54.530', 102),CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-02 08:38:06.460', 102),'SIX001','SIX001',0)
--ERROR--EOleException--------------------------------------------------------------------
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]Algemene netwerkfout. Raadpleeg de netwerkdocumentatie
On script:  insert into t_intervention_mission (RowID,IntCardRowID,MissionRowID,Duration,Number,InCalculation,KindRowID,WorkTime,WorkOut,ImmovableProperty,VatPercent,DurationChange,DefaultMissionPrice,ProductCount,DeliverProductPrice,DeliverWorkPrice,DeliverTransportPrice,DeliverMissionPrice,DeliverTotalPrice,ActiveProductPrice,ActiveWorkPrice,ActiveTransportPrice,ActiveMissionPrice,ActiveTotalPrice,TariffRowID,WorkCostPercent,WorkCostPlus,WorkAmountPercent,WorkAmountPlus,ProductAmountPercent,ProductAmountPlus,TransportCostPercent,TransportCostPlus,TransportAmountPercent,TransportAmountPlus,MissionAmountPercent,MissionAmountPlus,DateCreate,DateChange,WorkStationCreate,WorkStationChange,ContractPrice) values ('{53C5780D-B683-45C9-B942-018091DD0435}','{0709FB3B-1CDD-4E2B-BAC6-4FB6A952F788}','{C24234F2-DD1F-4B3B-B81D-3D13384CC573}',CONVERT(DATETIME,'1899-12-30 00:20:00.000', 102),1,0,'{77387E4C-604A-4653-B490-38A6B9C5A8E5}',0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13.54,11.01,0,24.55,'{DADB09D9-A760-4213-98AA-47E090EAB1FD}',0,0,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-02 08:37:54.530', 102),CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-02 08:38:06.460', 102),'SIX001','SIX001',0)
Connection:AdoConnectionServer
Number =-2147467259
NativeError =11
Source =Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Description =[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]Algemene netwerkfout. Raadpleeg de netwerkdocumentatie.
Helpfile =
SQLState =HY018
--21/10/2013 14:11:37----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get to the technician on the floor. I run the old synchro app with the old function TLogFile.SqlExec (StrSql : String; AdoConnection : TADOConnection; ARec: _RecordSet): Integer;
and the script doesn't give me an error. 
What is wrong about the AdoConnection.Execute(StrSql, cmdText) VS oQuerySql.ExecSQL;
The adoconnection and the scripts are done in a thread.

On older laptops (Windows XP), I don't have this issue. 
Only for the new laptop with Windows7.

If someone can give me some clarification or tips where to search the problem. I will appreciated it.
Is there also diffence between 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' and 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'.

For the synchronization I use the 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server'

Comment: Well just to exclaim right off the bat, SQL Native Client (SQLNCLI) is not pre-installed with Windows. Some things such as Visual Studio or SQL Server might install this, but it does not come with Windows.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I was already changing the code to SQLNCLI. Thanks for the tip. I will rollback the code and use only the SQLOLEDB.1

Comment: Did this help with your issue?

Comment: No, you just give attention not to use SQLNCLI because this is not pre-installed on Windows. Also I get not all the time the general network error. Therefore it is difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask the problem to the firm of the laptops (Panasonic).
Panasonic give me a Firmware update and driver installation and this solve the problem.
I don't get the network error anymore.